# Programming in Linux (C++)

Tags: c++, linux, operating-systems

So I don't know If this is the right place to ask this. I am new to programming, I am not very in to it (I know classes,arrays,functions..etc(Basic Things)).

I was programming with Visual Studio 2013 , so I decided to change my OS to Linux.

First things I notice is that the code is not exactly the same also the including headers. For example: I can't use conio.h and with it I can't end my main function with _getch(); function.

My question is: What's the difference between windows and linux programming? Can someone recommend me where can I look/read for this changes(whats the different and what can I use with linux).

Any help will be appreciated! Thank you in advance !! :)

Comment: off-site resource recommendations are explicitly off-topic per [help/on-topic] (it's the same here as at Stack Overflow). See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6483/why-was-my-question-closed-or-down-voted/6487#6487

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also be interested in the system programming aspect of your task. Then read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/), read the [intro(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/intro.2.html) & [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) man pages.  Be aware of the [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/) standard.

For thread programming, read a good [Posix thread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or a C++11 thread tutorial.

Regarding C++ programming, the [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) and [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) projects should interest you (and also perhaps [Boost](http://www.boost.org/)): they provide you with a cross-platform framework.

Regarding tools and programming habits, see [these hints](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7937638/841108).

I recommend using at least [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11), not some earlier C++ standard (see documentation on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) & on [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com), etc...). So use *recent* versions of compilers (e.g. [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) 4.9 or [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) 3.5 at least, in spring 2015). Don't forget to enable all warnings and debug info.

Study the source code of some existing [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software) (see e.g. [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) or [github](http://github.com/), etc...), you'll learn a big lot. Try even to contribute to it.

BTW, learning *other* programming languages (e.g. Scheme with [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/), Haskell, Ocaml, Prolog, Python, ...) will also teach you a big lot (even improve your way of thinking in C++).

Comment: This is a nice answer, regarding the systems programming.  Except that – unless the OP wants to understand how the operating system thinks about threads – I would strongly recommend studying the C++11 thread model.  Of course, on GNU/Linux, C++11 threads will very likely be implemented using Pthreads so most things you read about Pthreads should be applicable.  But then, you are again depending on knowledge of low-level implementation details.

Comment: Agreed, but the Posix thread tutorial gives explanation that are relevant to C++11 threads.

Answer (score 2):

There are the features that the language provides, and there are other features that the OS provides. `iostream` for example is built in to the language. `conio.h` is specific to Windows. There are other headers too that are specific to Linux.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you find differences is that the C you are using is not GNU C or ANSI C. It's better if you learn the language well instead of trying to find the differences.

I'd suggest referring

C: [The C Programming Language, 2nd Edition](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131103628) by Brian W. Kernighan  and Dennis M. Ritchie

C++: [The C++ Programming Language (3rd Edition)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201889544) by Bjarne Stroustrup

Comment: Its the 4th edition better?\

Comment: @Huntix 4th edition focuses more on C++11 features. But is a good read anyway.

Comment: Defenitely read the 4th edition.  C++11 almost feels like a new language that is safer, faster and much more enjoyable to program.  You really want to learn the modern usage, not the technology that was used a decade ago.